# Scaling images with CSS proportionally

Tags: css

I'm working on a fluid layout and I'm having trouble with scaling images. I've been using absolute width and height lately, but that's causing problems in many instances.

My source image is 1642px wide by 760px high.

Is there a way to do something involving percentages, much like you can proportionally scale an image in Photoshop? Say I want the image's height to be the same as the height of its container, but the width to be proportional in that sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is specify only image height, and width will scale proportionally.

```
img{
    height:100px;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jncnE/

Answer (score 0):

Has not worked for me in any variation, even with !important. Specifying just the height limit squashes the image and the width doesn't scale, and vice versa.

I found the solution on another thread here. You have to set one dimension to auto, depending on your need.

```
.containerName {
width: auto;
height: 150px !important;
}
```

I use important to override another setting I can't change.